# SQL Plus - Different columns with the salary of each department_id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to show for each job_id its salary in the column of the department_id.

Example from my teacher [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yoF6.png).

For now I've done this, but i don't know how to show only the salary for each column of department.

```
SELECT job_id, SUM(salary) "Dep20", SUM(salary) "Dep50", SUM(salary) "Dep60", SUM(salary) "Dep90", SUM(salary) "Total"
FROM employees
WHERE department_id IN ('20', '50', '60', '90')
GROUP BY job_id;
```

Result in [SQL Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM3Pz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT job_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN department_id = 20 THEN salary END) as Dep20,        
       SUM(CASE WHEN department_id = 50 THEN salary END) as Dep50,        
       SUM(CASE WHEN department_id = 60 THEN salary END) as Dep60,        
       SUM(CASE WHEN department_id = 90 THEN salary END) as Dep90,
       SUM(salary) as Total
FROM employees
WHERE department_id IN (20, 50, 60, 90)
GROUP BY job_id;
```

I am guessing that `department_id` is a number -- that values are certainly numeric.  Numbers should be compared to numbers, not strings, so I removed the single quotes.

Also, there is no need to escape the column aliases, so the double quotes are superfluous.